# Якорные аккордеоны

Tags: javascript, html, css, jquery

Ребят, привет. Подскажите, как реализовать открытие аккордеона через якорные ссылки? Пример [тут](https://steampay.com/support/payments). Самое главное, чтобы в url без перезагрузки также менялось значение якорной ссылки. Подскажите, как реализовать?

```css
.content {
    display: none;
  }
```

```html
<div class="block">
  <a href="#21">
    Заголовок
  </a>
  <p id="21" class="content">
    Содержимое 
  </p>
</div>
```

Comment: А что за аккордеон? (то, что это музыкальный инструмент, я знаю)

Comment: @gil9red http://w3.org.ua/jquery/jquery-pishem-akkordeon-s-primeneniem-effektov/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вот так)

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.accordion__trigger').click(function(event) {
    if ($('.accordion').hasClass('closeall')) {
      $('.accordion__trigger').not($(this)).removeClass('active');
      $('.accordion__content').not($(this).next()).slideUp(300);
    }
    $(this).toggleClass('active').next().slideToggle(300);
  });
});
```

```css
.accordion__content {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<ul class="accordion closeall">
  <li class="accordion__item">
    <a href="#" class="accordion__trigger">
      <span>Аккордеон 1</span>
    </a>
    <div class="accordion__content">
      Lorem ipsum perspiciatis.
    </div>
  </li>
  <li class="accordion__item">
    <a href="#" class="accordion__trigger">
      <span>Аккордеон 2</span>
    </a>
    <div class="accordion__content">
      Lorem ipsum perspiciatis.
    </div>
  </li>
  <li class="accordion__item">
    <a href="#" class="accordion__trigger">
      <span>Аккордеон 3</span>
    </a>
    <div class="accordion__content">
      Lorem ipsum perspiciatis.
    </div>
  </li>
</ul>


<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: А почему в URL нечего не меняется? Всё круто конечно) "Самое главное, чтобы в url без перезагрузки также менялось значение якорной ссылки."